# What does “ using a lower estimate” mean?

Tags: meaning

reading forbes 400 about airbnb founders. the context is the following:

> The airbnb founders’ net worths are down versus a year ago because Forbes is **using a lower estimate** of their ownership stakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an estimate is an educated guess or calculated approximation of some metric, such a calculation will be bounded by upper & lower values based on the range of possible values for some parameters which affect the result.

Therefore, in your quote, the phrase *"Forbes is using a lower estimate"* essentially means that they are using an estimate at the lower end of the possible forecasted outcomes which have been calculated from the available data. Some might describe this as a 'conservative estimate'.

Comment: so basically they can evaluate on upper or lower estimate. last year was on upper estimate now is on lower estimate. thank you very much I didnt know that

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby There is a common saying that statistics can be manipulated to show anything :-)